# Convert A Char To Keys

Tags: c#, char, key, special-characters

I have a special char (/ @) That I want to convert to Keys.

I am currently using this :

```
Keys k = (Keys)'/';
```

And while debugging, I get that k equals to :

> LButton | RButton | MButton | Back | Space type - System.Windows.Forms.Keys

k's keycode was suppose to be 111.

NOTE: The code does work for uppercase letters such as :

```
Keys k = (Keys)'Z';
```

In that case, k's key code is 90, which is ok.

I'm trying to find a way to convert special chars to Keys. (or to their proper key code)

Trying to send keys globally using :

```
public static void SendKey(byte keycode)
    {
        const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        keybd_event(keycode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
        keybd_event(keycode, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
    }

SendKey((byte)Keys.{SomethingHere});
```

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to do with this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast from char to Keys.  Keys is a flags enumeration that represents which physical keys are pressed on the keyboard.  What you are trying might not be a straightforward problem to solve.  Who's to say what keyboard the user used and what mapping generates what particular character on the user's keyboard and their locale?

Can you be more specific about your goal?  Are you trying to teach a user how to type a special character or something else?

Based on your update, you should be using the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class.

Comment: WOW that saved me some trouble and I didn't think it'll work because I'm sending it to another application that might have protected itself.

Comment: @user779444: I once did something similar, but just wanted to let you know that when the computer is locked, the keys won't go through. For example, if you'd start your program emulating keys and lock the computer ([Windows key] + L) it would stop working.

Comment: According to Vano Maisuradze's answer, it is indeed possible to cast from char to keys.

Comment: SendKeys is useless, because it cannot send keys to a process. It can only send keys to the "active window", which is unreliable. We need an easier way to map a string to keystrokes to send to an application. It's very difficult to automate something like launching a bash window and getting data into it.

Answer (score 18):

It's old question, but I used this:

```
Keys k = (Keys)char.ToUpper(c);
```

If char value is **a** (with code 97) then converting into **A** (with code 65) maps to **Keys.A** and so on...

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This is actually the only working solution and shows char can indeed be casted to Keys.

Comment: This works great except the Keys enum only has lowercase values when you push this to a keyboard typing command in User32.DLL such as using the infamous KeyboardSimulator library.  In order to support uppercase letters, one needs to check if(char.IsUpper(c)) and if so, issue a Keys.ShiftKey key down event, do a key press event on the letter, then a key up event on shift, which is how a keyboard converts lower case to upper.

Answer (score 2):

It should work!

Keys o = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), ((int)e.KeyChar).ToString());

Comment: Sorry, still getting LButton | RButton | MButton | Back | Space

Answer (score 1):

My way only works with letters and some other keys.

```
string s = char.ToString(e.KeyChar);
```

This gives you string of Keys equivalent. Something like output of `Keys.ToString()`. So all we need that converting `s` to its Keys equivalent!

```
(Keys) Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), char.ToString(e.KeyChar).ToUpper());
```

good luck...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this the ideal solution in terms of readability.

```
Keys key = (Keys) Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), c.ToString(), ignoreCase: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to map the `Keys` enumeration to `char`. One specifies key codes and modifiers, useful for `System.Windows.Forms.Control` while the other represents a 16 bit Unicode character (U+0000 to U+ffff).

To alltogether different concepts.