# How to identify small and large letters in the keyboard?

Tags: c#, hook, keyboard-hook

How do I capture both big and small keys through `(Keys) Marshal.ReadInt32 (lParam)` + checking Shift.

I want to learn how to capture all keyboard keys, but I do not know how to do it correctly.

```
public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private static readonly LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;

private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
  if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
  {
    try
    {
       Console.WriteLine((Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam));
    }
    catch (AccessViolationException ex) { Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.ToString()}"); }
  }
  return NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

A lot is not understandable. And how can you define character keys?

Is it possible to convert keys ToUnicodeEx?

Comment: Maybe check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201882/convert-a-char-to-keys  Or this:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/582165f8-ff32-4cb9-907e-fe968a841b5d/converting-keys-to-characters?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: just check if caps or shift is pressed. but there might be a better way for sure

Comment: @sLw, Can you give an example please?

Comment: Even if the shift key is pressed, the int you get may not be the sort of thing that can be "upper case". This feels like you should be able to get a Char representation somehow and something like `isUpper()`

Answer (score 0):

Check my keylogger fucntionalities [Here](https://github.com/DzNiT0/Keylogger) :

the functions you may wanna check them :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            try {
                gHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook(); // Create a new GlobalKeyboardHook
                                                  // Declare a KeyDown Event
                gHook.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gHook_KeyUp);
                gHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gHook_KeyDown);
                // Add the keys you want to hook to the HookedKeys list
                foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
                    gHook.HookedKeys.Add(key);
            }
            catch (Exception z)
            {

            }

        }

public void gHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            String getCharVar = getCharDown(e.KeyValue);
           if(getCharVar!=null)
                richTextBox1.Text += getCharVar;

        }



private String getCharDown(int Value)
        {

            if (Value > 95 && Value < 106)
                return ((char)(Value-48)).ToString();

            if (Value > 64 && Value < 91)
            {if(!Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
                return ((char)(Value+32)).ToString();
            else
                    return ((char)(Value)).ToString();
            }
            if (Value > 47 && Value < 58)
                return ((char)Value).ToString();


            return null;
        }
```

**PS:** You can rebuild the project so you can test.